# Can VS Code format a selection of text as something other than what the file type suggests?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working in a .cfml file, which is almost entirely HTML, and the little bit that isn't could be treated as such.

However, VS Code seems to refuse to format this file for me because it doesn't know what a .cfml file is.

Is there anyway I can tell VS Code to just format it as html anyway?  Something like "Format Selection as..."?  I'd even be ok with formatting the whole file, but it would be better for selected text if possible.

Comment: Can you just save the file as HTML, then format it, then save it back as cfml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case, you can use the `files.associations` setting to just make VS Code treat files with the `.cfml` extension be treated as HTML files.

Like so (put in a [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)):

```json
"files.associations": {
    "*.cfml": "html"
}
```

If you want to make the change temporarily and easily reversibly, then just use the `Change Language Mode` command in the command palette, or click the language mode indicator at the bottom right of the screen, which opens a menu to select a non-persisted language mode. ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_change-the-language-for-the-selected-file)).

As for your more general question "*Can VS Code format a selection of text as something other than what the file type suggests?*", I'm not aware of a way to do that if the file already has a file type association that you *don't* want to override.

Comment: Change Language Mode is exactly what I was looking for (minus the ability to do selected text I think but its good enough and better than renaming a file).